# how to download apk file to nand flash internal memory not having SD Card?

Tags: java, android

My code for downloading apk to SD card which is working fine in emulator and android devices having SD Card. I m developing app for android stick which has Nand Flash/Internal Flash not SD card.How can I get the path of Nand flash "download" forlder..How can I find the path of download folder in NandFlash?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/internalmemory/Download/newversion.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without /mnt/sdcard  this flag android returned a intent error!
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I find the path of download folder in NandFlash?

The same way you hopefully found the "path of download folder" everywhere else:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`
```

You can read more about `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29). You might also consider reading the more general documentation about [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Comment: I tried this it gave me "/mnt/sdcard" .  NandFlash is internal memory not external. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RickyWatson: `/mnt/sdcard` is what is known as a "directory". It contains "files". Where this "directory" resides depends upon the implementation of the device. For a few hundred million Android devices, `/mnt/sdcard` will point to on-board flash memory. If you would take the time to read the documentation that I linked to, you would have learned this already. Please read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal